# Pointer in c++for scanning an array

Tags: c++

How to scan an array in c++ using pointer?

I have learned c programming .so i tried that way.

```
include<iostream>
using namespace std;
main()
{
int a[5],*p,i;
p=&a[5];
for(i=0;i<5;i++)
{
cout<<"enter"<<i+1<<endl;
cin>>(p+i);

}
for(i=0;i<5;i++)
{
cout<<*(p+i)<<endl;
}
}
```

I am expecting to  scan using pointer just like in c programming

Comment: Voting to close as a typo.  You used the wrong value.  `p=&a[5];` should be `p=&a[0];` so `p` is at the start of the array, not the end.

Comment: You took an address of element past the end of the array and you went even further than that...

Comment: `p=&a[5];` points one past the end of `a` (legal).  You then increment and de-reference `p` this is Undefined Behaviour

Comment: "I have learned c programming" you haven't done that successfully.  it should be `p=&a[0]` or equal and even shorter `p = a`, and would work exactly the same in C++

Comment: this is my first time using stack overflow.thanks u guys for quick support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> p=&a[5];
> ```

`&a[5]` is the address to one past the last element of the array. Incrementing this pointer, as well as indirecting through the pointer have undefined behaviour.

What you need is a pointer to the first element. You can use:

```
p = &a[0]; // this
p = a;     // or this
```

Or you could simply not use `p` in the first place, and access `a[i]` directly.

---

> ```
> cin>>(p+i);
> ```

This is wrong. `p+i` is a pointer. You cannot extract into an int pointer. You should extract into the integer object instead:

```
 cin >> p[i];
 cin >> a[i]; // or without p, as I pointed out above
```

Comment: now  i got it.thank u.

Comment: @SachinKuttoth Indeed they are the addresses of those respective elements. But you aren't reading an address; you're reading an integer, so you must pass an integer as operand.

Comment: `why cin>>(p+i); is wrong ` because `(p+i)` is of wrong type. `and cin >> p[i] works?` Because `p[i]` is of correct type. `since p is a pointer not an array ?` Same applies to `a + i` and `a[i]`. Latter is a correct operand for stream extraction and former is not. As I said, `p + i` does indeed hold the address of the element `p[i]` that is why it is wrong operand for the stream extraction. You are not reading an address, you're reading an integer, so you pass an integer as an operand. You don't pass a pointer as the operand.

Comment: scanf("%d",(p+i));  works for me in c. so is that due to the typespecifier??

Comment: @SachinKuttoth scanf is a completely different function. It cannot work the same way stream extraction works because there are no references in C.